# Akka: model of Network with actors

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I have a task to model an interaction between nodes of net, by using Akka aktors.
Target model contains nodes, each of which either send and receive messages to other nodes.

So within actor approach, each actor, before getting started, must obtain references on all other actors, to which it send messages.

It would seem, the simple way to pass this refs through constructor params:

```
  val node1 = context.spawn(Node(), "node1")
  val node2 = context.spawn(Node(node1), "node2")
```

The problem is that node1 does't get in constructor the ActorRef on node2. If there were way to update actor "node1" after creation with ref on "node2", the problem does not appear. But, as I understand, update actors is not provided by Akka.

Other (working) way, which I found, it to use special inial-message:

At first, parent actor spawn childs:

```
  case class Refs(Set[ActorRef[Node]])

  val node1 = context.spawn(Node(), "node1")
  val node2 = context.spawn(Node(), "node2")
```

At second, it send them message, which contains set of refs on each created child actor.

```
  val refs = Inialise(Set(node1, node2))

  context.children.foreach(child => child ! refs)
```

And only after receive Inialise-message each child begin send and receive any messages.

Is there any other way (patterns) to realise solve this task? In  https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/interaction-patterns.html#scheduling-messages-to-self    [Interaction Patterns](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/interaction-patterns.html#scheduling-messages-to-self) I also didn't find any variants.

I looked to the side of EventBus and preStart lifecycle method, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Levi's answer is detailed and correct. But I wanted to reiterate that I'm not sure why you think you can't update actors. Actors, almost by definition contain state can modify that state in response to messages. (Such as the AddLink messages Levi suggests.)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to realize a defined topology, sending `Initialise` messages after all the actors are set up is likely to be the clearest way to accomplish that.

An alternative approach is to allow the set of nodes which a node is linked to to be more dynamic, with an `AddLink` (or whatever) message, which is sent when a node is started with links to existing nodes:

```scala
val node1 = context.spawn(Node(), "node1")
val node2 = context.spawn(Node(node1), "node2")
```

And when node2 starts it sends an `AddLink(context.self)` message to node1, since *it* knows about node1.

Another alternative might be for the creation of a node actor to require a reference to an actor which can answer the question "with whom should I be interlinked?" (this actor could be the parent or even the guardian actor for the `ActorSystem`, but even there, explicitly passing an `ActorRef` (rather than relying on `context.parent` or `context.system`: either of those requires an `unsafeUpcast`) is probably better).  On startup, your nodes make an ask of that actor, which tracks pending requests, the desired topology, and which actors have made an ask (thus registering themselves) so that it replies once all of the nodes the asker is linked to exist.

Comment: Levi, its interesting variant, but one clarification. It works well for 2-3 actors. But what about 100 and more? (It is my case). As I understand, 100-th created actor must provide broadcast send AddLink-message to all previous-created 99 actors. Respectively, 99-th - to 98 previous-created... So, the cost of broadcast is defined by the sum of series: 99 + 98 + 97 + 96 + 95....    And proposed by me  way with one Initialise-message assume broadcast with only 100 messages.

Comment: In general, as David notes, any update of an actor in Akka is going to involve an asynchronous message send (because anything else would basically be throwing away nearly every advantage of using Akka).